# RequestProfiler and LongRun Command Target

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to track down the cause of slowness for a customer. It is rather hit or miss as to when it happens. When looking through the Request Profiler output we see LongRun Command Targets. What are they?

Answer (score 0):

Request profiler shows each request when the long running process check for the process state. This is a short request that contains no useful info.
However when process is completed it will be another record added that will provide full processing details based on the action selected in the processing screen.